# Does Azure Active Directory support the JWT bearer token flow?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

We have a number of services that can be called by users via HTTP based protocols (SOAP/REST/WebDAV). The services support various authentication mechanisms (e.g. Basic, and OIDC Bearer tokens). Sometimes a service has to call another service without a live user. For that, we configure technical users, and service A can call B with the credentials of a technical user.

For OAuth/OIDC authentication via Bearer tokens, we use the JWT bearer token flow to acquire access tokens for our technical users: Service A creates a JWT with the name of the technical user and signs it with its own private key. It then calls the OIDC token endpoint with that token and receives an access token for its technical user X. It can then use this token as a bearer token to call service B, which will accept the token for user X. (For more information on the JWT bearer flow, cf. RFC 7523 section 2.1 and RFC 7521 section 4).

This works fine with our Connect2id test server and also with Salesforce, but we haven't been able to get it working with Azure. Accessing Azure's token endpoint always results in the following error response:

> AADSTS50027: JWT token is invalid or malformed

According the Microsoft's documentation, this error can have any number of reasons:

- doesn't contain nonce claim, sub claim
- subject identifier mismatch
- duplicate claim in idToken claims
- unexpected issuer
- unexpected audience
- not within its valid time range
- token format is not proper
- External ID token from issuer failed signature verification.

When trying to find out more about Azure and the JWT bearer flow, the only solid information I've been able to locate is this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

It describes the "On-Behalf-Of" (OBO) flow, which as far as I understand is an extension (by Microsoft?) to the JWT bearer flow, adding a second JWT to the mix along with a parameter called "requested_token_use" set to "on_behalf_of". I can only find "requested_token_use" in relation to the special OBO flow, and its only value seems to be "on_behalf_of".

OBO flow isn't what we want, since it seems to allow a service X to turn a token received by service Y into another token, using the Y token and a self-generated X token to call the token endpoint. Our use case only has a self-generated X token and the name of the user who the app is permitted to impersonate.

After a lengthy trial & error phase we've come to the impression that OBO may in fact be the only (non-standard) version of the JWT bearer flow that Azure knows about, and that it may not support the "normal" JWT bearer flow we're trying to use at all. Is this correct, and we have no option but to give up trying to solve this scenario with standard OIDC when Azure is involved, or does Azure in fact also support the flow we've implemented and we're just doing something wrong (e.g. wrong audience or issuer in our JWT, or a mis-configured app in Azure)?

PS: Our code is written in Java and we use the Nimbus library for our OAuth/OIDC communication.